# Insert into #tmp select * from transTable error not going into catch block

Tags: try-catch

I have a "Insert into #tmp Select * from TransTable" statement within TRY block. This statement generates an error because #tmp has an identity column. But after error is raised, control does not go to CATCH block. Error raised has severity of 16 and hence as per my understanding it should go to CATCH block. Kindly explain as to why is this happening.

Let me elaborate the question , below is the scenario where we are going to dump records from one table to another but due to Identity (not turned on) it throw an error while execution. The expectation here is, it should go to catch block where as it doesn't any thought?

Create table TableA
(
ID int identity,
Value varchar(1)
)
Create table TableB
(
ID int identity,
Value varchar(1)
)

insert into TableA values ('A')
insert into TableA values  ('B')
insert into TableA  values ('C')
insert into TableA  values ('D')
insert into TableA  values ('E')

Begin Try
Truncate table TableB
Insert into TableB Select * from TableA
End Try
Begin Catch
SELECT 
        ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber,
        ERROR_SEVERITY() AS ErrorSeverity,
        ERROR_STATE() as ErrorState,
        ERROR_PROCEDURE() as ErrorProcedure,
        ERROR_LINE() as ErrorLine,
        ERROR_MESSAGE() as ErrorMessage;
End Catch

Error :
**Msg 8101, Level 16, State 1, Line 26
An explicit value for the identity column in table 'TableB' can only be specified when a column list is used and IDENTITY_INSERT is ON.**

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not mistaking, when you're using SQL calls you need to "catch" SQL exceptions, which are different to regular exceptions.

What programming language are you using? What DB are you using? Could you post a sample code?

This is an example:

```
Try
    ' Execute insert statement
Catch sqlEx as SqlException
    ' Do something about the SQL exception
Catch ex as Exception
    '  Regular exception
End Try
```